# Populate Data in DropDownList in Create Mode MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to populate data from table in DropDownList using MVC4. Trying to figure it out how to get all the languages' titles into the DropDown in the Edit mode.

Models:

```
public class CategoryLanguage
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int LanguageID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

public class Language
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            using (MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())
            {
                ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Languages, "ID", "Title");
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Emp/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CategoryLanguage newCatLang)
        {
            using (MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.CategoryLanguages.Add(newCatLang);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.Languages, "ID", "Title", newCatLang.LanguageID);
                return View(newCatLang);
            }
        }
```

View:

```
@model MultilanguageCategories.CORE.Models.CategoryLanguage

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Add New Item</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        @Html.DropDownList("ID", "--Select--")
}
```

Trying to figure it out how to get all the languages' titles into the DropDown when creating new CategoryLanguage entity. The error says: "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed." and this line marked: @Html.DropDownList("ID", "--Select--")

Comment: instead of `ViewBag` try to save it in `Model`

Comment: can u give me a sample?

Comment: Add one field selectlist field in `Model` then try like this `Model.ID=Select...`

Comment: @Nilesh : Can you make it more clear ?

Comment: @StiliyanVasilev : check my answer. may be it can help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your get method **"Create"** as mentioned below :

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var languages = new List<Language>();
    using (MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())
    {
        languages = db.Languages.ToList();
    }

    ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(languages, "ID", "Title");
    return View();
}
```

Now you can use **DropDownListFor** as mentioned below :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.[PropertyName], (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ID)
```

Comment: you cannot get values of `languages` outside `using` block

Comment: Are you sure about this ? Coz before posting answer here, first I write sample code and test.

Comment: Great, your code works perfectly in my case SpiderCode. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you're close...

You need to Add the languages select list to the viewbag (which you've already done, but with a badly named key)

ie: `ViewBag.LanguagesList = new SelectList(db.Languages, "ID", "Title");`

if you want an empty field that's easy enough too:

```
var langs = db.Languages.ToList().ConvertAll(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.ID, Text = x.Title });
langs.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "--Select--" });
ViewBag.LanguagesList = langs;
```

The DropdownList should be for a property in the model.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LanguageID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LanguagesList)
```

As it looks like you are using an Entity Framework class as your model you need to ensure the context is not disposed before the view is rendered.

As Per Microsoft's example [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4) instantiate the context at the top of the controller, and drop the using statement in the Create method.

ie :

```
public class LanguageCategoryController : Controller
{
    MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
            ViewBag.LanguagesList = new SelectList(db.Languages, "ID", "Title");
            // or replace the above line with the other example above
            // if you want the empty "--select--" option

            return View();           
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done that but it still has an error: "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed" and marked in red the following line: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LanguageID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LanguagesList)

Comment: I'm going to assume that is because the Model being used is an Entity Framework class, and the context is disposed before the view is loaded. If you look at Microsoft's Example here: [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4) You'll notice that the context is constructed at the top of the controller class, and there is no using statement (so it will only get disposed when the controller gets disposed - which doesn't happen until after the view is rendered). I'll update my answer to show this.